# Sign in into google with firebase via flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin, flutter-dependencies

i have created this new project for me where i am not having any kind of error, but i cant see my users in firebase. i cant turn my navigator here, which should automatically turn on after i sign in. though asap the app opens it shows the google accounts, here is the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'chat app',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
        accentColor: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

here is  my homepage where the sign in occurs

```
// /import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/create_account.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import './pages/timeline.dart';
import './pages/upload.dart';
import './pages/activity_feed.dart';
import './pages/search.dart';
import './pages/profile.dart';

final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final usersRef = Firestore.instance.collection("users");
final timestamp = DateTime.now();

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isAuth = false;
  int index = 0;
  PageController pageController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: 2);
    googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount account) {
      handleSignIn(account);
    });
    googleSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((account) {
      handleSignIn(account);
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  handleSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    if (account != null) {
      setState(
        () {
          isAuth = true;
        },
      );
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isAuth = false;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> createUserInFireStore() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.document(user.id).get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
      String userName;

      userName = await Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (conetext) => CreateAccount()));

      userRef.document(user.id).setData({
        "id": user.id,
        "userNAme": userName,
        "photoUrl": user.photoUrl,
        "email": user.email,
        "displayName": user.displayName,
        "bio": "",
        "timeStamp": timestamp
      });
    }
  }

  login() {
    googleSignIn.signIn();
  }

  logout() {
    googleSignIn.signOut();
  }

  onPageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      this.index = index;
    });
  }

  onTap(int index) {
    pageController.animateToPage(
      index,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
  }

  Widget buildAuthScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(child: Text("logout"), onPressed: logout),
          //  Timeline(),
          ActivityFeed(),
          Upload(),
          Search(),
          Profile(),
        ],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot), title: Text("timeline")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active),
              title: Text("activity feed")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.photo_camera,
              ),
              title: Text("upload")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search), title: Text("search")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), title: Text("profile")),
        ],
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
          size: 35,
        ),
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        onTap: onTap,
        currentIndex: index,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
      ),
    );
  }

  Scaffold buildUnAuthScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                colors: [
              Colors.pink,
              Colors.purple,
            ])),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              elevation: 8,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topRight,
                        end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        colors: [
                      Colors.purple,
                      Colors.pink,
                    ])),
                child: Text(
                  "Whore Market",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Bebas",
                    fontSize: 80,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => login(),
              child: Container(
                width: 260,
                height: 60,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/google_signin_button.png"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isAuth ? buildAuthScreen() : buildUnAuthScreen();
  }
}
```

here is the page i want to navigate to

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/header.dart';

class CreateAccount extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateAccountState createState() => _CreateAccountState();
}

class _CreateAccountState extends State<CreateAccount> {
  String userName;
  final _formKey =GlobalKey<FormState>();
  submit() {
  _formKey.currentState.save();
  Navigator.pop(context, userName);
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: header(context, title: "set up your profile"),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 350,
              child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    onSaved: (val)=> userName = val,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: "username",
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                hintText: "must have 8 char"),
          ))),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: submit(),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0)
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Submit",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[the code is also available here](https://github.com/shah-rahul/flutter-)

Comment: You legit corrected my English daymmn.

Answer (score 1):

in your 'CreateUserinFireStore' function, change the code inside the If condition to following,

```
 if (!doc.exists) {
      await userRef.document(user.id).setData({
        "id": user.id,
        "userNAme": userName,
        "photoUrl": user.photoUrl,
        "email": user.email,
        "displayName": user.displayName,
        "bio": "",
        "timeStamp": timestamp
      });
      Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (conetext) => CreateAccount()));
 }
```

Comment: Bro I get username from the navigator I can't do that. Simple logic. Anyways I fixed it. Just by changing the format of navigator to another type.